# csrf token is not send in fetch api headers

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to send a fetch api request with post method to my backend. I do can get csrf token from my cookies in front-end but I do not know why this csrf token is not set in my fetch api headers.
Any help?

```
function getCookie(name) {
  if (!document.cookie) {
    return null;
  }

  const xsrfCookies = document.cookie.split(';')
  .map(c => c.trim())
  .filter(c => c.startsWith(name + '='));

  if (xsrfCookies.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return decodeURIComponent(xsrfCookies[0].split('=')[1]);
}

function getHeader() {
  const csrfToken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  console.log('csrftoken:', csrfToken) // csrf token is logged in console
  const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    });
  return headers
}

function sendCartDataToBackend(userCartObject) {
  let sendingJSON = {
  "body" : `${userCartObject}`
  }
  headers = getHeader()
  console.log('headers:', headers) // csrf token is not in headers!!!
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/order/new/", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(sendingJSON),
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed new Headers() and problem solved.

```
  const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).